# Prove that if $G$ acts properly on $X$, the quotient map $\pi: X\to X/G$ to the space $X/G$ of orbits is a covering.

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, group-actions, topos-theory

This is **Exercise II.3** of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's, *"Sheaves in Geometry and Logic [. . .]*". According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=acts%20properly%2C%20orbits%2C%20quotient&p=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

<strike>From Mac Lane and Moerdijk, p. 37</strike>

> **Definition 1:** Given an object $C$ in the category $\mathbf{C}$, a *sieve* on $C$ [. . .] is a set $S$ of arrows with codomain $C$ such that
>
> $f \in S$ and the composite $fh$ if defined implies $fh \in S$.

From p. 70 *ibid.* . . .

> **Definition 2:** A sieve $S$ on $U$ is said to be a *covering sieve* for $U$ when $U$ is the union of all the open sets $V$ in $S$.

From the exercise *ibid.* . . .

> **Definition 3:** An [action](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)) $G\times X\stackrel{\cdot}{\to}X$ of a group $G$ on a space $X$ is said to be *proper* if for every point $x\in X$ there exists a [neighbourhood](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) $U_x$ of $x$ with the property that $g\cdot U_x\cap U_x\neq \varnothing$ implies $g = 1$ for all $g\in G$.

From p. 82 *ibid.* . . .

> **Definition 4:** A *covering map* $p: \stackrel{\sim}{X} \to X$ is a continuous map between topological spaces such that each $x\in X$ has an open neighborhood $U$, with $x\in U \subset X$, for which $p^{-1}U$ is a disjoint union of open sets $U_i$, each of which is mapped [homeomorphically](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) onto $U$ by $p$.

### The Question:

> Prove that if $G$ acts properly on $X$, the quotient map $\pi: X\to X/G$ to the space $X/G$ of orbits is a covering.

### Thoughts:

Let $G$ act properly on a topology $X$, denoted $(g, x)\mapsto g\cdot x$.

My first thought is to consider finite $G$ or finite $X$ to make the problem tractable. To this end, let $G$ be the trivial group.

<strike>Then, indeed, for all $x\in X$, we have that, since $X\in\mathcal{O}(X)$, there exists a neighbourhood (namely, $X$), for which, for any $g\in G$, if $g\cdot X\cap X\neq \varnothing$, then $g=1$. This is far from edifying though. One can see clearly that $X/G$ is in bijection with $X$ (I think) and, indeed, all open sets are subsets of $X$. Thus $\pi:X\to X/G$, as described in the exercise, is a covering.</strike>

But I'm not sure about that last sentence. Does it even make sense?

> Does one have to consider $\pi$ and $\{\pi\}$ as roughly the same thing to fit into **Definition 1** and **Definition 2**?

I feel way off.

Where do I go from here?

Please help :)

Comment: Is there any reason you are using their definition of a covering map? (Which is the least transparent definition of a covering map I have ever seen.)

Comment: To stay consistent with Mac Lane and Moerdijk, @MoisheKohan.

Comment: Then, I suggest you use their definition of a covering map from page 82, which is very standard and with which the solution of the exercise is quite easy.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! Thank you, @MoisheKohan :)

Comment: I suppose you already figured out how to solve the exercise, in which case, I suggest you answer your own question. Incidentally, their definition of a proper action is very nonstandard.

Comment: Definition 1 and 2 in your post have nothing to do with _covering maps_, it defines the notion of a _covering sieve_.

Comment: That's why I have them crossed out, @Pece.

Comment: I have edited the question, @MoisheKohan. I'm afraid I haven't figured out the solution yet. I'd appreciate a hint or something to get me going.

Comment: I've edited the question, @Pece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that the action $G\times X\to X$ is proper in the sense of this book (which is a nonstandard definition by the way). Given $x\in X$, show that $V=\pi(U_x)$ is a neighborhood of $y=\pi(x)$ in $Y=X/G$. Now, describe the preimage  $\pi^{-1}(V)$ as a disjoint union of suitable open subsets of $X$. Analyze the restriction of $\pi$ to these open subsets. ... Conclude that $\pi: X\to Y$ is a covering map.